# Populating values from earlier records based on column value in Spark query

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to write a Spark SQL (2.4) query to determine and populate column value from earlier records based on a (`srvc_typ`) column/condition -

Source:

```
id | policy | prsn | prv  | srvc_typ
1  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  proc
2  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  drg
3  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  drg
4  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  proc
5  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  drg
```

Requirement:

Within a particular group of records (key: policy, prsn, prv), populate the id column as -
Within a particular group if the `srvc_typ` of any record is `'drg'` then populate its id column with the id value of its **last encountered** non-drg record - i.e. srvc_typ <> 'drg'.
If the srvc_typ of any record (within that same group) has srvc_typ = 'proc' then retain its own id.

Expected output: (Note the changes in the id column)

```
id | policy | prsn | prv  | srvc_typ
1  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  proc
1  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  drg
1  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  drg
4  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  proc
4  | 1234G  | xyz  | prv1 |  drg
```

Explanation:

- Since the first record is of `srvc_typ = 'proc'`, its original `id`
  value is retained i.e. `1`
- Now, for the second and third rows,
  their `srvc_typ` value is `'drg'`, hence the `id` column of these rows
  are to be changed to their **last encountered** non-drg (proc) record
  i.e. `1` (record number 1)
- The fourth record has `srvc_typ = 'proc'` hence it retains its original id value i.e `4`
- Now, the fifth and final record has a type of `'drg'` hence its id value should change
  and hence should be equal to its last encountered `'proc'` record i.e. `4` (record number 4)

There could be multiple occurrences of `proc` records in the same group as shown above.

Can someone please help me write the query in Spark SQL using the %sql% api.

Happy to provide additional information if required.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [window function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html#syntax) (eg. [`last_value`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#aggregate-functions)) to look at previous rows, and a [`CASE`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-case.html) statement to only take `srvc_typ = 'proc'` into account. That's the working query:

```
WITH input (id, policy, prsn, prv, srvc_typ) AS (
    SELECT 1, '1234G', 'xyz', 'prv1', 'proc'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '1234G', 'xyz', 'prv1', 'drg'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '1234G', 'xyz', 'prv1', 'drg'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '1234G', 'xyz', 'prv1', 'proc'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '1234G', 'xyz', 'prv1', 'drg'
)
SELECT last_value(CASE WHEN srvc_typ = 'proc' THEN id END, TRUE)
                  OVER (
                      PARTITION BY policy, prsn, prv
                      ORDER BY id
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                      ) AS id,
       policy,
       prsn,
       prv,
       srvc_typ
FROM input
```

| id | policy | prsn | prv | srvc_typ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234G | xyz | prv1 | proc |
| 1 | 1234G | xyz | prv1 | drg |
| 1 | 1234G | xyz | prv1 | drg |
| 4 | 1234G | xyz | prv1 | proc |
| 4 | 1234G | xyz | prv1 | drg |

*) I ran it with spark `3.0.1` - hopefully the version `2.4` has all the sql implemented. But even if not, you get the idea - I am sure you can also pull it off using the imperative style.